# Getting (401) Unauthorised in PayPal Vault payment, works fine in sandbox

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm able to store a card in the PayPal Vault in production, read a card, delete a card, and enumerate all the cards in the vault using C# and the PayPal SDK's.  However, when I try to use a card stored in the vault to make a purchase, I get a (401) Unauthorised error.  This purchase works fine in the PayPal Sandbox but fails in production when it hits the line:

```
var createdPayment = payment.Create(ppc.apiContext);
```

Walking through the debugger, I have the config setup for live, apiContext, transaction, and credit card token... they all look correct.

I'm not sure if this is a technical issue or whether the company just needs to have certain "permissions" enabled like Direct Credit Card Payments or something like that.

I have a ticket opened in PayPal MTS but so far, no help.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's not a technical issue at all, it's permissions at the company level.  We had log on, go to the Dashboard, My Account, and enable "Direct Credit Cards".  You then have to fill out an application and submit it.  We were contacted by e-mail with a few questions, provided three months of bank credit card statements, and were approved.  Once that happened, we were able to make purchases with credit cards stored in the PayPal Vault.   Would be nice if they told you that up front somewhere...